# Visual Studio function IIF

Tags: visual-studio, iif

I use Visual Studio 2017, and I have an expression like this:

```
=Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.Trim(Fields!QUESTION.Value) & 
   " Average:" &
    ROUND(AVG(fields!Multiple_Choice_Value.value), 2) &
    "(Range"  &
    Min(Fields!Multiple_Choice_Value.Value) &
    "- " &
    Max(Fields!Multiple_Choice_Value.Value) &
    ")"
```

output as "`Procedures Average:85(Range 85-100)`

I need to change this code: if `Multiple_Choice_Value` is null, output will be only `Not Observed`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this:

```
=IIF(Fields!Multiple_Choice_Value.Value Is Nothing, "Not Observed", 
    Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.Trim(Fields!QUESTION.Value) & 
       " Average:" &
        ROUND(AVG(fields!Multiple_Choice_Value.value), 2) &
        "(Range"  &
        Min(Fields!Multiple_Choice_Value.Value) &
        "- " &
        Max(Fields!Multiple_Choice_Value.Value) &
        ")"
    )
```